# Windows Phone 8 Server Connection

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am want to make a 'hello world' application whereby I can send some data/make a request to a server or a WCF service. A simple query, save, delete etc application. I am targeting this learning app to be on the Windows Phone 8 platform.

I have done some work in WCF and RavenDB in the past but, not sure what to do in this situation.

Can someone please give me some tips/tutorials on how to achieve this please?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used WCF to create a Service. The Service contained an Interface which were operations that were exposed and they were implemented in a different file. I then created a windows phone app and added the Service Reference by providing a URL to the service. The code to query the service was simply:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client myClient = new Service1Client();
        myClient.AddNumbersCompleted += new EventHandler<AddNumbersCompletedEventArgs>(myClient_AddNumbersCompleted);
        myClient.AddNumbersAsync(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

    }

    void myClient_AddNumbersCompleted(object sender, AddNumbersCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = "Answer:" + e.Result.ToString();
    }
```